# Wrapper and scanner classes in Java

Tags: java, wrapper

These are the instructions for the assignment:

```
    For this Question, you will be using two of the prominent wrapper classes to convert String variables
    which represent numerical data into primitive types as instances of the wrapper classes. 
    As part of this Question you will be using a Scanner object to read in user input.
    There are also 2 previously declared and instantiated String object references, value1 and value2
    that you will use as part of this exercise. 

    1) Declare an int variable with the identifier parsedInt, and double variable with the identifer parsedDouble
    2) Use a static method of the Integer class to convert the String object reference value1 to an int
        and assign that value to the parsedInt variable. 
    3) Use a static method of the Double class to convert the String object reference value2 to a double
        and assign that value to the parsedDouble variable. 
    4) Declare 2 Double variables with identifiers of your choosing.
    5) Declare an instantiate a Scanner variable (object reference) with the identifier of your choosing
        Make sure that it can read from the Java console (System.in) and that you have imported the Scanner class
    5) Using a static method of the Double class, convert String values read in from the console
        (by calling the nextLine method on your Scanner object reference) to the Double type 
        and assign them to the two Double object references declared in the previous step. 
    6) Declare 2 boolean variables with the identifiers isInfinite and isNaN
    7) Call methods on your Double object references to make the following tests and store the result in the proper variable
        Use a method to test if the first value that you read in from the console is Infinite
        Use a method to test if the second value that you read in from the console is Not a Number (NaN)
    8) Declare an int variable result 
    9) Convert the values of the two Double object references to integers
        and subtract the second number that was read in from the first that was read in
        and assign the result of that mathematical expression to the variable result
```

My problem starts at number 5. I'm not quite sure what I'm being asked to do and I don't know how to convert the string values to doubles. This is what I have so far:

```
    double woof1, woof2;
    boolean isInfinite, isNaN;
    int result;

    Integer parsedInt = new Integer(value1);
    Double parsedDouble = new Double(value2);

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
```

**Update**
Now I have this

```
    double woof1, woof2;
    boolean isInfinite, isNaN;
    int result;

    Integer parsedInt = new Integer(value1);
    Double parsedDouble = new Double(value2);

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    woof1 = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
    woof2 = Double.parseDouble(scan.nextLine());
```

and now I'm not sure how to do number 7.

Comment: I'm inclined to leave this open. Christine did not dump a "give me the code" question. Rather, she is working through each of the requirements. There will be plenty more to close in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First - you've got the reference for scanner.  That's a start, but I'd recommend that it come before you declare any of your other numerical types.

Second - all of the numerical wrappers, such as `Integer`, `Long`, and `Double` support a `parse###` method, which includes the name of the primitive type that they're parsing.  They take a `String` as their formal argument.  As an example, for the `Integer` wrapper, its parse method is `Integer.parseInt()`.

Third, reading a line from a `Scanner` instance is as simple as `scan.nextLine()`.  If that line contains the number you want to parse, and you want to parse a `Double`, then consider what `Double.parse###` actually is.  I leave this as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: So your latest edit has it better... But you really should get rid of value1 and value2 since neither variable exists.

Comment: They do exist, they've already been declared by the professor in some other code.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do

```
double parsedDouble = Double.parseDouble(scan.nextLine());
```

However, this is a stupid question because it would be better to do

```
double parsedDouble = scan.nextDouble();
```

Comment: What makes that better?

Comment: I would argue its better because its more concise.  But whatever

Comment: It is indeed more concise and makes a better use of `Scanner`. If this method exist, why bothering with doing it by hand ? (EDIT : when I say it is a stupid question, I talk about the assignment, not the OP)

Comment: So if I do it the first way you mentioned, do I still need the     
       Double parsedDouble = new Double(value2) ?